# Excel formula to calculate based on pieces required, pieces per box and shipments per day

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need a formula that will calclate the pieces required for each shipment as close to equally as possbile based on the amount of pieces in a box.   I need it to calculate the shipments to match the answers I put in.
The shipments are 4 per day.

Below is a picture of what I am trying to accomplish (the pieces on shipment 1 holds the remainder of the sum of the other shipments).
[image]
** The formula that I am needing is required to determine the number of pieces on each shipment.   The answers I have in there is what I need the forumla to calculate for**.

As data:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | Pieces Required | Pieces per box | Pieces Shipment #1 | Pieces Shipment #2 | Pieces Shipment #3 | Pieces Shipment #4 |
| **2** | 1323 | 27 | 351 | 324 | 324 | 324 |

Comment: Please add the table from the linked image right into your question. Questions here are meant to be potentially useful for a longer time than external image providers store them. Also please add more details, like are the number of pieces per box and the number of shipments fixed for the formula? And are you hence basically looking for the flat quotient of boxes divided by shipments, adding the remainder to the first shipment(s)?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SU. What have you tried so far?

Comment: When you say "shipment 1 holds the remainder", should it be more balanced or not? ie if you require 1350 pieces, should it be 378/324/324/324 or 351/351/324/324 ?

Comment: @ FlexYourData:  I tried using the formula suggested by P.B.  This did not seem to work.

Comment: @ssssteffff:  Target pieces is 1323.   Shipment 1 would be 351.  The other 3 would be 324.  I want the largest on the first truck.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a way in Office 365:

```
=LET(s,4,
     i,INT(A2/B2/s)*B2,
EXPAND(i+MOD(A2,i),,s,i))
```

Where `s` is the number of shipments. You could change that to refer to a cell value, or calculate that by dividing the total number by the max number of boxes allowed per pallet.